# I don't understand what instruction "and ax, 1111111100000000b" is doing

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I have been given  some code, and I understand most of it, and know what happens. I'm having a problem understanding this piece of the code:

```
div bl
and ax, 1111111100000000b
```

I think the first line is just a simple division, but what is the `and ax, 1111111100000000b` doing?

The full code is:

```
section .data
number db  5
answer db  1
section .bss
section .text
    global _start
_start:
       mov esi, number
keith: mov eax, 0
       mov al, [esi]
       mov dl, al
       mov bl, 2
loopy: div bl         ; ax / bl with quotient in al and remainder in ah
       and ax, 1111111100000000b
       cmp ax, 0
       je  there
       inc bl
       cmp bl, dl
       je done
       mov eax, 0
       mov al, [esi]
       jmp loopy  
                     ; restore the  number back into
                     ; ax
there: mov byte[answer], 0
done:
       mov eax,1       ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
       mov ebx,0       ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
       int 80h
```

Comment: It's a 16-bit binary value, and the instruction will clear the 8 l.s. of `ax` and retain its 8 m.s. bits. If you read the comment on the `div bl` line above, it tells you why.

Comment: @MartinJames is that really the best you could of done? I'm asking a question to educate myself and try and understand! You did NOT have to tell me what i should or shouldn't be doing. If you want to help but you think that the part i don't understand is to long to explain refer me to some readings to do or a similar example. If you don't want to help you don't even need to make a comment. Just imagine yourself driving a car and it breaks down.. how would you like the mechanic to come and tell you "if you don't understand simple mechanics you should not be using a car."

Comment: @WeatherVane simple and straight forward, thank you. I appreciate your help, and respect the fact that you didn't try to tell me I'm an idiot.

Comment: To learn what `and` does (and actually a lot more than that function), look in [Intel's Reference Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html): "**Volume 2**: Includes the full instruction set reference, A-Z, in one volume. Describes the format of the instruction and provides reference pages for instructions."

Comment: @lior yu can drive the car, but you have a problem and have completely disassembled the entire vehicle to try and fix it, even though you are baffled by all those pipes, wires and bolts:(    'is that really the best you could of done?' no.  For free, yes.   SO is not a personal tuition site, and youir question on basic logical operations is not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 2):

I think **it would have been clearer to write it as `and ax, 0xFF00`**, since counting eight 1s and eight 0s is harder for human readers.

Better would be `xor al,al` to zero the low byte (but that produces a partial-reg slowdown when reading the full `ax` after writing `al`).

---

Actually, **the code is just a really silly way to check that the remainder is zero**.  The whole code is pretty braindead.  Use `movzx` to load a byte with the upper bytes zeroed, not `mov eax,0` / `mov al, [mem]`.

For the test, just `test ah,ah` / `je there` to test the remainder directly.  The `and ax` also sets ZF iff the remainder is zero, so `and ax, 0xFF00 / jz there` is also equivalent.  This is just bad code.

Here's a rewrite:

```
section .data
number   db  5
is_prime db  1             ; we store a zero if it's not prime

section .text
global _start
_start:
       movzx  edx, byte [number]  ; there was no need to put the pointer in a register
       mov    ecx, 2

;; This whole algorithm is very naive.  Slightly better: check for even (low bit), then only check odd divisors.  Google for stuff that's better than trial division.
.trial_division:
       mov    eax, edx   ; fresh copy of number.  cheaper than re-loading from cache
       div    bl         ; ax / bl.  quotient in al.  remainder in ah
       test   ah,ah      ; set flags based on remainder
       jz    .found_divisor

       inc    ecx
       cmp    ecx, edx    ; upper bound only needs to be sqrt(number), but we're aiming for small / simple code, not efficiency apparently
       jl    .trial_division  ; the final conditional branch goes at the end of the loop

       jmp   done
.found_divisor:
       mov byte[is_prime], 0
done:
       mov   eax,1       ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
       xor   ebx,ebx     ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
       int   80h
```

So in the loop there's only one not-taken branch, and then looping with a taken conditional branch.  It hardly matters since `div` throughput is the only bottleneck, but in general try to keep insn out of your loop if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `div bl` operation performs the following operation:

> DIV r/m8 --- Unsigned divide AX by r/m8, with result stored in AL ← Quotient, AH ← Remainder.

So your code

```
keith: mov eax, 0
   mov al, [esi]
   mov dl, al
   mov bl, 2
```

sets up AX with the first 8 bits of `byte ptr [esi]`, saves these lower 8 bits and then divides this value by `bl=2`.

```
loopy: div bl         ; ax / bl with quotient in al and remainder in ah
   and ax, 1111111100000000b
   cmp ax, 0
   je  there
```

The previous lines are somewhat awkward, because `and ax, 1111111100000000b` just sets `AL=0` - it `AND` masks the lower 8 bits of `AX`. An alternative would have been to `MOV AL,0`.

After that, it compares `AX` to zero, which is kind of overcomplicated, because `AL` has just been set to zero.

The (in your case) easiest (and most comprehensible way) would have been the following code:

```
  mov esi, number
keith: 
  movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]   ; or byte [esi] if your using NASM
  mov dl, al                  ; saving this byte
  mov bl, 2
loopy: 
  div bl                      ; ax / bl with quotient in al and remainder in ah
  cmp ah, 0                   ; is remainder = 0 ?
  je  there                   ; then go to 'there'
...
```